# Search Highlights in file Contents

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We have .net application displaying data from using Azure Search service, based on [DotNet search App Template](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-knowledge-mining/tree/master/02%20-%20Web%20UI%20Template)

Is there a possibility to show only parts of the file with the highlighted term - for example PDF file page with term highlighted on top?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked up using the highlight feature?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#highlightstring-optional

Your search results will then have a new @search.highlights field which contains a collection of passages with the searched terms. Then you can also use the $select parameter to decide which fields to retrieve and which one to ignore.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#selectstring-optional